# Proof of a real eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a $2\times2$ matrix

$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b \\ c&d\end{pmatrix}$.

I found the characteristic polynomial which is $T^2-(a+b)T+ad-bc$.
It can be written as $T^2-T(\operatorname{tr}(A))+\operatorname{det}(A)$.

Now, how do I prove that $A$ has real eigenvalues if and only if $\operatorname{det}(A) \leq ((\operatorname{tr}(A)/2)^2$?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: I edited your question just a tad to make the notation more consistent, and set up the $2 \times 2$ matrix.  Hope it's OK.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Quadratic equation has real roots iff $D \ge 0$. In your case $ D = (tr(A))^2 - 4det(A) \ge 0 $. Hence matrix has real eigenvalue iff $ (tr(A))^2 \ge 4det(A) $, equivalent $ det(A) \le (tr(A)/2)^2 $

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The [discriminant](http://www.mathwords.com/d/discriminant_quadratic.htm) has to be non-negative to have real roots of a quadratic.